# Como editar o CSS de um iFrame?

Tags: css

> Preciso colocar um `iFrame` em meu site que utiliza o seguinte código:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&amp;w=h&amp;c=474647&amp;f=ffffff" height="180px" width="211px"></iframe>
```

**Como posso fazer para editar o CSS do conteúdo que é exibido?**

Queria mudar algumas cores, backgrounds, etc...

Teria como adicionar uma nova folha CSS?

Ou adicionar o `CSS Incorporado` mesmo?
Ex:

```
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    .classe { background: #000;
    }    
    #id { background: #FFF;
    }
    </style>
```

> Link do iFrame: http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&w=h&c=474647&f=ffffff

Comment: O iFrame esta no mesmo dominio que o seu site?

Comment: Não conheço as implicações de segurança do CSS, mas a princípio eu diria que você não pode modificar **nada** no conteúdo de um `iframe` que não pertença à mesma origem (esquema, domínio e talvez porta) da sua página principal. O máximo que você pode fazer - se o browser der suporte - é colocar o `iframe` num sandbox, bloqueando Ajax, JavaScript, etc (nesse caso, para página principal se proteger contra conteúdo malicioso embutido). Mas modificações arbitrárias, receio ser impossível, e com boa razão.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, removi a resposta... pensei que fosse possivel

Comment: Se você criar um tipo de proxy carregando o conteúdo usando o curl, você conseguiria modificar o que quisesse antes de imprimir...

Comment: Veja se isto pode ajudá-lo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: Não @Sergio está em um site externo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui fazer apenas com jquery usando um proxy, agora basta trabalhar com o css e o script para funcionar as tabs, <strike>mas isso deixo com você</strike>:

**jquery:**

```
$('#divframe').load(
    'http://www.corsproxy.com/' +
    'www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&amp;w=h&amp;c=474647&amp;f=ffffff .tabtop',  function() {
         $('#divframe').html( $('#divframe').html().replace(new RegExp('src="', 'g'),'src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/') );
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divframe"></div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/kuLdmnm4/

EDIT: jsfiddle com o script das tabs funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/kuLdmnm4/2/

---

**Alternativa com proxy próprio em PHP:**

**proxy.php** (com apenas esse conteúdo, e mais nada)

```
<?php
$cache_file = 'proxy_cache.html'; // nome do arquivo para salvar cache

if (!@file_exists($cache_file) || (time() - @filemtime($cache_file) > (60 * 60 * 6))) { // verificar se o cache expirou e fazer uma nova requisição ao cptec.inpe.br
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&amp;w=h&amp;c=474647&amp;f=ffffff");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $retorno = str_replace('src="','src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/',curl_exec($ch)); // adicionar o endereço absoluto a todos os src
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents($cache_file, $retorno); // salvar conteudo no arquivo de cache
} else { // cache não expirou abrir o conteudo do arquivo sem nova requisição ao cptec.inpe.br
    $retorno = file_get_contents($cache_file);
}

echo $retorno; // imprimir o conteudo
?>
```

> **O conteúdo abaixo deve estar em outro arquivo**, juntamente com o css e
>   tudo mais...  arquivo ex: [teste.html](http://pastebin.com/77RFXdf5)

**jquery:**

```
$('#divframe').load(
    'proxy.php .tabtop',  function() {
         $('#divframe .tab_content').hide();
         $('#divframe .tabs li:first').addClass('active');
         $('#divframe .tab_content:first').show();
         $('#divframe .tabs li').click(function(){
             $('#divframe .tabs li').removeClass('active');
             $(this).addClass('active');
             $('#divframe .tab_content').hide();
             $($(this).children('a').attr('href')).show();
         });
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divframe"></div>
```

Comment: O Proxy que você deixou está funcionando 100%! Só não entendi essa parte do cache. Porque esse cache?

Comment: Para não precisar fazer uma requisição ao cptec.inpe.br a cada pageview no seu site... coloquei a atualização a cada 6 horas.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Aqui pra mim o proxy.php é instantâneo, dá só uma piscadinha, e também estou rodando no localhost...

Comment: @AlexandreLopes Verifique se ele esta criando o arquivo de cache, pois se pegar no cache, deve ser mais rápido ainda...

Comment: @AlexandreLopes tem coisa errada no seu iframe.php pois ele esta abrindo todo o conteúdo que deveria abrir apenas  no proxy.php, depois no final tem uma requisição ajax, chamando por um proxy.php que não existe no servidor... acho que você não entendeu como deveria ser...

Comment: Mas do jeito que eu fiz (Tudo em 1 só) ficou melhor, carrega tudo normal e sem problemas. Funciona tudo 100%. E agora? Posso continuar usando assim? Ou estou errado?

Comment: Leia com atenção a resposta, crie o arquivo proxy.php para ser chamado pelo .load e use esse [arquivo](http://pastebin.com/77RFXdf5) como base para testar, corrija apenas a chamada do jquery `<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` para apontar para um local/arquivo correto.

Comment: Esta certo é isso ai mesmo, agora basta corrigir o CSS como você desejar, e para fazer o fade mude a linha `$($(this).children('a').attr('href')).show();` para `$($(this).children('a').attr('href')).fadeIn();` Você não quer que eu me divirta sozinho né? Faça um pouco também, afinal o proposito disso é aprender a fazer e não copiar e colar.

Comment: Desculpe, é que eu não entendo, aí complica. kkkk... Seu script está perfeito, excelente, sem comentários.

Comment: Ficou perfeito muito obrigado! Agora vamos apagar alguns comentários pois já fizemos muita baderna, rsrs... Você é muito legal, muito obrigado por ter gastado seu precioso tempo com o noob aqui. kkkkk... Vlw

Comment: olha esse outro: http://radioinhumasfm.com/iframe/frame2.html Quando você clica em alguma `tab` a página dá um `scroll` sozinho.

Comment: É como se fosse um `link ancora` apontando para `tab_content`

Comment: @AlexandreLopes tente mudar de: `$('#divframe .tabs li').click(function(){` para: `$('#divframe .tabs li').click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Funcionou! Você é o cara, você é demais! Ebaaaa....
É que salvou com cache aí eu pensei que não tinha prestado, mais ficou 100%! Você é o cara!

Comment: Queria ser tão sábio quanto você... Sou noob! :(

Comment: heheh que bom que funcionou @AlexandreLopes

Answer (score 1):

Por definição, o iframe permite abrir um documento externo, seja ele no mesmo servidor ou em outros. Algumas soluções em javascript podem ajudar a fazer o que você quer, mas apenas se for um documento no mesmo servidor.

Portanto, em princípio a resposta é não.

Mas, você pode criar uma cópia da página externa no seu servidor usando PHP:

```
file_get_contents(/* string: url da página */)
```

E aplicar os estilos CSS que quiser na string retornada, podendo criar até uma "versão" da página original no seu servidor, com seus próprios estilos e scripts.

Comment: Você poderia ser mais específico? Não sou muito bom com PHP, o ideal seria você publicar um código mais completo, eu não sei o que colocar em `/* string: url da página */`

Comment: Não funciona com JS e CSS relativos como os do IFRAME

Comment: Como assim @PapaCharlie ?
Queria tipo usar o CSS Incorporado mesmo.

Comment: o widget precisa de JS para mudar as abas, CSS para imagens e afins... Pelo que vi do widget, os caminhos são relativos, você precisaria dos caminhos absolutos

Comment: Faça um teste: `file_get_contents( 'http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&w=h&c=474647&f=ffffff' )`

Comment: Eu utilizei: `<?php
file_get_contents( 'http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&w=h&c=474647&f=ffffff' )
?>` e não apareceu nada, simplesmente deu página branca.