# Iframe modo responsivo para dispositivos móveis

Tags: html, css, iframe

Alguém me sabe dizer como tornar um `iframe` responsivo para dispositivos mobile?

Comment: O `iframe` mesmo ou o conteúdo dentro do `iframe`?

Answer (score 1):

**Exemplo usando boostrap:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d467688.89495119266!2d-46.5952992!3d-23.6824124!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce448183a461d1%3A0x9ba94b08ff335bae!2sS%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1429724267414" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Exemplo usando div qualquer:**

HTML

```
<div id="MolduraIframe">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d467688.89495119266!2d-46.5952992!3d-23.6824124!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce448183a461d1%3A0x9ba94b08ff335bae!2sS%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1429724267414" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#MolduraIframe{
// Defina as resoluções para adaptar o tamanho conforme cada caso
@media (max-width:100px){
// Defina o tamanho que o objeto terá com tal resolução
}
}
```

**Em resumo:** Você deverá colocar o `width` e o `height` para 100% e o adapte a base de uma `div` externa responsiva.

Se você quer alterar o conteúdo do IFRAME e tornar o mesmo responsivo, ai já é outra história. Sugiro que leia: [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe), [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/28106/como-editar-o-css-de-um-iframe) e também, [isso](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/423876-como-mudar-o-css-de-um-iframe-a-partir-de-uma-pgina-pai/)